# How to use single html.erb file for multiple actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create multiple function but each functions render to its data to single file as like simple php, is possible with ruby and rails. I tried to found this but search results are not as per my point of view.

Comment: Section 2.2.3 in this guide will help you: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partials will help you:

1. Create view than you want show in other views, name it `_your_view.html.erb`
2. Include it in other views:

```
<%= render :partial => 'path/to/your/partial/your_view' %>
```

Path can be skipped if your partial is in `/app/views` root folder, not in subfolders.
Don't forget remove first `_` symbol from partial name while including (file is `_your_view.html.erb` and including is `your_view`).

Also you can pass parameters into partial:

```
<%= render :partial => 'path/to/your/partial/your_view', :locals => {:param1 => 'value1' } %>
```

and use them in partial:

```
<% value = local_assigns[:param1] %>
<%= text_field_tag :param1, :value => value %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You should look at using custom View helpers. For start, look at these links:

http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-view-helpers-in-rails-4
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers.html